# Migrate DB2 Stored Procedure to Oracle

Tags: oracle, stored-procedures

I have a Db2 stored procedure, with multiple cursors and i would open any of the cursor based on some conditions, PFB the SP,

```
CREATE PROCEDURE SAMPLEPROCEDURE (
    IN "IN_PARM1"   CHARACTER(3),
    IN "IN_PARM2"   CHARACTER(3),
    IN "IN_PARM3"   CHARACTER(3),
 )
  SPECIFIC "SAMPLEPROCEDURE"
  DYNAMIC RESULT SETS 1
  LANGUAGE SQL
  NOT DETERMINISTIC
  NO EXTERNAL ACTION
  MODIFIES SQL DATA
  OLD SAVEPOINT LEVEL
P1: BEGIN

        DECLARE CURSOR1 CURSOR WITH RETURN FOR      
         --My Select query goes here
        DECLARE CURSOR2 CURSOR WITH RETURN FOR      
        --My Select query goes here
        DECLARE CURSOR3 CURSOR WITH RETURN FOR          
        --My Select query goes here  
  IF IN_PARM1 <> '' OR IN_PARM1 IS NOT NULL THEN    
    IF IN_PARM2 <> '444' THEN    
            OPEN CURSOR1;
        ELSE
            OPEN CURSOR2;
    END IF;
  ELSE
        OPEN CURSOR3;
  END IF;
  END P1
```

How could i create a similar kind of procedure in Oracle. Please help me out in this

Answer (score 0):

It looks not much different in Oracle's PL/SQL:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE SAMPLEPROCEDURE (
   IN_PARM1 VARCHAR2,
   IN_PARM2 VARCHAR2,
   IN_PARM3 VARCHAR2) 
AS
  CURSOR CURSOR1 IS SELECT ...;
  CURSOR CURSOR2 IS SELECT ...;
  CURSOR CURSOR3 IS SELECT ...;
BEGIN
  IF IN_PARM1 IS NOT NULL THEN
    IF IN_PARM2 <> '444' THEN
      OPEN CURSOR1;
    ELSE 
      OPEN CURSOR2;
    END IF;
  ELSE 
    OPEN CURSOR3;
  END IF;
END SAMPLEPROCEDURE;
/
```

Comment: And what is the equivalent of `DYNAMIC RESULT SETS 1`?

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name: You're saying the answer is wrong?

Comment: I don't know. But this "dynamic result sets" looks like something that doesn't have a direct equivalent in Oracle. Procedures in Oracle can't return a "result set" unless you use a ref cursor as an output parameter.

Comment: But unlike in Db2 when i run the SP where i get the output of the cursor, in oracle i am not able to get the result while running the SP, only when i return the cursor through any output cursor variable like SYS_REFCURSOR it is getting returned